# problema con mostrar vendedores en c++

Tags: c++, visual-studio, archivo

Buenas estoy trabajando con archivos en *c++* y estoy haciendo una especie de almacén que guarda los datos de vendedor y producto, pero mi problema es que cuando cierro el programa y vuelvo a iniciarlo y uso a opción 2 de buscar vendedor aparece como que no hay vendedores a pesar que anteriormente ingrese a la opción 2 con sus productos, aquí esta el código:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>
#include <fstream>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define MAXCAD 50
#define MAX_V 100     // numero de vendedores
#define MAX_PV 100    // maximo de productos vendidos

using namespace std;

struct unProducto {
    char name_prod[MAXCAD];  // nombre del producto
    int  cantidad;
    int  precio;
    int  subtotal;
};

struct variosProductos {
    int numProd;             // numero de productos por vendedor
    unProducto vp[MAX_PV];      //varios productos cada uno en una posicion del  vector
    int precioTotal;
};

struct Vendedor {
    char nombre[MAXCAD];
    char apellido[MAXCAD];
    char direccion[MAXCAD];
    int  DNI;
    variosProductos P;
};

struct Vendedor lista[MAX_V]; // creamos un array de tvendedores
struct Vendedor aux;


void registrar_productos(int nv, int np){
    // nv -> numero de vendedor
    for (int i = 0; i<np; i++)
    {
        cout << "\n\tProducto " << i + 1 << endl;cin.ignore();
        cout << "\t\tNombre   : ";cin.getline(lista[nv].P.vp[i].name_prod, MAXCAD);

        //cin.ignore();
        cout << "\t\tCantidad : ";cin >> lista[nv].P.vp[i].cantidad;
        //cin.ignore();
        cout << "\t\tPrecio   : ";cin >> lista[nv].P.vp[i].precio;

        lista[nv].P.vp[i].subtotal = lista[nv].P.vp[i].cantidad * lista[nv].P.vp[i].precio;  // subtotal = precio*cantidad
        if (lista[nv].P.vp[i].subtotal == 0)
            cout << "Subtotal 0";
        lista[nv].P.precioTotal = lista[nv].P.precioTotal + lista[nv].P.vp[i].subtotal;

    }
}
void registrar_vendedores(int n){
    ofstream g("reg_vendedores.dat", ios::out | ios::binary | ios::app);
    int np;  //  numero de productos por cada vendedor
    for (int i = 0; i<n; i++)
    {
        cout << "\nVENDEDOR " << i + 1 << "\n";
        cin.ignore();  cout << "   Nombres   : ";  cin.getline(lista[i].nombre, MAXCAD);
        cin.ignore();  cout << "   Apellidos : ";  cin.getline(lista[i].apellido, MAXCAD);
        cin.ignore();  cout << "   Direccion : ";  cin.getline(lista[i].direccion, MAXCAD);
        cin.ignore();  cout << "   D N I     : ";  cin >> lista[i].DNI;

        cout << "\n   > Numero de productos: ";      cin >> lista[i].P.numProd;

        registrar_productos(i, lista[i].P.numProd);
        g.write(reinterpret_cast<char *>(&lista[i]), sizeof(Vendedor));
    }g.close();
}

void datosVendedor(int x, int num){
    if (num>0)
    {
        cout << endl << endl;
        cout << "\t" << lista[x].nombre << ' ' << lista[x].apellido << endl;
        cout << "   DNI      :  " << lista[x].DNI << endl;
        cout << "   Direccion:  " << lista[x].direccion << endl;
    }
    else
        cout << "\n\tRegistro vacio..!";
}

void prodVendedor(int x, int num)
{
    if (num>0)
    {
        cout << endl << endl;
        cout << "   Productos de " << lista[x].nombre << ' ' << lista[x].apellido << endl << endl;

        for (int i = 0; i<lista[x].P.numProd; i++)
        {
            cout << "\n   Producto " << i + 1 << endl;
            cout << "\tNombre  : " << lista[x].P.vp[i].name_prod << endl;
            cout << "\tCantidad: " << lista[x].P.vp[i].cantidad << endl;
            cout << "\tPrecio  : " << lista[x].P.vp[i].precio << endl;
            cout << "\tSubtotal: " << lista[x].P.vp[i].subtotal << endl;
        }
        cout << endl;
        cout << "  ---------------------------" << endl;
        cout << "  PRECIO TOTAL:   " << lista[x].P.precioTotal;
    }
    else
        cout << "\n\tRegistro vacio..!";
}

void mostrar_productos(int nv){
    cout << "   Productos: \n\n";
    for (int i = 0; i<lista[nv].P.numProd; i++){
        cout << "\t- " << lista[nv].P.vp[i].name_prod << endl;
    }
}

void mostrar_vendedores(int num){
    ifstream mv("reg_vendedores.dat", ios::in | ios::binary);
    if (num>0){
        cout << "\n\nMostrando lista de Vendedores\n";
        while (!mv.eof()){
            for (int i = 0; i < num; i++){
            mv.read(reinterpret_cast<char *>(&lista[i]), sizeof(Vendedor));
                if (!mv.eof()){
                    cout << endl << endl;
                    cout << i + 1 << ". " << lista[i].nombre << ' ' << lista[i].apellido << endl;
                    cout << "   DNI      :  " << lista[i].DNI << endl;
                    cout << "   Direccion:  " << lista[i].direccion << endl;

                    mostrar_productos(i);
                    cout << endl;
                }
            }
        }mv.close();
    }
    else
        cout << "\n\tRegistro vacio..!";
}

void eliminar_vendedor(int x, int &num)
{
    if (num>0)
    {
        for (int i = x; i<num - 1; i++)
            lista[i] = lista[i + 1];
        num--;
    }
    else
        cout << "\n\tRegistro vacio..!";
}

void buscar_vendedor(int num){
    int band = 0;
    if (num>0){
        for (int i = 0; i<num; i++){
            if (lista[i].DNI == aux.DNI){
                cout << "\n\n La direccion de " << lista[i].nombre << " "
                    << lista[i].apellido << " es : "
                    << lista[i].direccion << endl;
                band = 1;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    else
        cout << "\n\tRegistro vacio..!";
    if (band == 0)
        cout << "\n\n\tEl vendedor no fue encontrado..! :S" << endl;
}

void menu1()
{
    cout << "\n\t\tREGISTRO DE VENDEDORES\n\n";
    cout << " 1. Registrar vendedores                       " << endl;
    cout << " 2. Mostrar registro de vendedores y productos " << endl;
    cout << " 3. Mostrar datos de un vendedor               " << endl;
    cout << " 4. Mostrar productos vendidos de un vendedor  " << endl;
    cout << " 5. Eliminar vendedor del registro             " << endl;
    cout << " 6. Buscar direccion de vendedor por DNI       " << endl;
    cout << " 7. Salir                                      " << endl;

    cout << "\n Ingrese opcion : ";
}

/*                      funcion principal
------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/

int main()
{
    int num = 0;  // numero de vendores
    int op;   // opcion del menu
    int num_vendedor;
    system("color 0b");
    do
    {
        menu1();  cin >> op;
        switch (op)
        {
        case 1:
            cout << "\n Numero de vendedores: ";
            cin >> num;
            registrar_vendedores(num);  cout << endl;
            break;
        case 2:
            mostrar_vendedores(num);
            break;
        case 3:
            cout << "\n Ingrese numero de vendedor: ";cin >> num_vendedor;
            datosVendedor(num_vendedor - 1, num);
            break;
        case 4:
            cout << "\n Ingrese numero de vendedor: ";cin >> num_vendedor;
            prodVendedor(num_vendedor - 1, num);
            break;
        case 5:
            cout << "\n Ingrese numero de vendedor: ";cin >> num_vendedor;
            eliminar_vendedor(num_vendedor - 1, num);
            cout << "\n\n\t\tVendedor eliminado ..!" << endl;
            break;
        case 6:
            cout << "\n Ingrese numero de DNI: ";cin >> aux.DNI;
            buscar_vendedor(num);
            break;
        }
        cout << endl << endl;
        system("pause");  system("cls");
    } while (op != 7);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Tu programa no almacena la información en un medio persistente, tal como un archivo en el disco duro de tu computadora, una base de datos, etc.

Cada vez que tu *almacenas* información en la memoria principal de la computadora, que es lo que haces al declarar una variable y poner alguna información en ella, esta información existirá mientras tu programa esté en ejecución.

```
struct Vendedor lista[MAX_V]
```

Esta declaración reserva un bloque contiguo de memoria capaz de almacenar `MAX_V` registros de tipo `Vendedor` en la memoria principal (RAM) de la computadora donde se ejecuta el programa.

Para fines prácticos, podemos decir que al finalizar la ejecución de tu programa, esta memoria es *devuelta* al sistema operativo, que eventualmente la asignará a otro programa que la solicite y la información que eventualmente pudo estar almacenada allí se pierde para siempre.

De manera análoga, cada vez que inicias un programa, este solicita *memoria nueva* al sistema operativo. En lenguajes como c o c++, esta *nueva memoria* contiene *basura*. Es decir, valores aleatorios que pueden estar allí desde el arranque de la computadora o que otro programa que ya terminó su ejecución pudo almacenar en su momento allí.

En conclusión, si quieres preservar información entre distintas ejecuciones de tu programa como parte del aprendizaje de la programación, primero te recomiendo investigar sobre *archivos* o *ficheros*, y posteriormente sobre *bases de datos*.

Quiero finalizar diciendo que, en sistemas operativos modernos, como Windows o Linux, el manejo de memoria por parte del sistema operativo es mucho más complejo que lo que he descrito, pero una explicación más profunda queda fuera del alcance de esta respuesta. Si algún lector se interesa por el tema, puede iniciar leyendo sobre [memory management](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_management_(operating_systems)) y [virtual memory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_memory) (en inglés).